# Files location of Android Studio

Tags: 18.04, files, android

I installed Android Studio on Ubuntu 18.04. It's in the "Show Applications" window, but I don't see it in Files > other locations > computer > usr > share > applications. Where is it?

I found it in snap. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: `/usr/share/applications` generally consists of shortcuts of the app. Are you interested in locating the binary or the shortcut?